# Updated meta description is not being shown on the Google result page

Tags: seo, meta-description

The following is the updated meta description tag that is present on HTML output.

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Click to see the details of used Diesel Generator - 25 kVA with pictures and specifications, price- Rs.225000.0, State of Punjab. Buy and sell used machinery online!" />
```

It's been 5 days since I made this change and the Google SERP result still shows the old meta description which is:

> Click to see the details of used Diesel Generator - 25 kVA with pictures and specifications. Buy and sell used machinery online!

The old meta description doesn't have price and state if you observe.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 3):

Because I cannot yet comment, why in first place aren't you adding `<meta name="description" content="your content here" />`?

`og:` meta tags are for Facebook Open Graph. That would reflect when you try sharing the mentioned page on Facebook.

That being said, the description in the search result page is not directly picked from meta description always, if Google detects a better fitting description of the result elsewhere in the page.

Answer (score 2):

Google algorithm may not show meta title and description based on your written meta tags.

Google picks from the page content and creates what best for the user.

Having said that, if you optimise your page for certain keywords and write meta title and description accordingly then you may see that meta title and description more often.